# Measure is being summed up in Cognos

Tags: cognos

I'm having a weird issue with Cognos. You can see the issue in the below image:

[image: List result]

Each `Credit Alert` can have a single adjustment associated with it. But the amount is usually in the hundreds or thousands. But here clearly we just have a sum up of all the `Adjustment Amounts`.

Below I attached the Cognos Framework Manager model ([large image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O47w.jpg)) inside the modelling layer. As you can see `F_CREDIT_ALERT` has a link to `D_INVOICE_ADJ` which has a link to `F_INVOICE_ADJ` (which has the measures `Request Amount` and `GST` which are used to create the `Adjustment Amount ex GST`).

[image: Cognos Framework Manager model]

Any help with this issue would be very appreciated. Also any general tips/comments about the model would be helpful too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, generate the SQL from Report Studio to see what's happening (Tools -> Show Generated SQL). This will give us a good idea of what's happening.

Likely, it is an issue with circular joins in the model. Meaning, Cognos has more than 1 path from F_CREDIT_ALERT to F_INVOICE_ADJ (through either D_INVOICE_ADJ or D_SNAPSHOT_DATE). This exists in more than one place as well. Cognos is not smart in deciding which path; for the longest time, it just took the alphabetical first (it probably still does, but I havent had a model with this sort of join in a long time). You need to model around this - one way is to create more than one instance of some objects, such as D_SNAPSHOT_DATE.

Do you plan on making this available in Query Studio? I foresee major aggregation issues given the multiple fact tables and circular joins. You may need to create smaller marts in the vein of a simple star schema. Some modelling behaviors may be easier to handle by creating SQL views which join at the proper level of aggregation.

I wrote this up for some of our new developers last year, it may be of some help if you're trying to create a robust, mature model: http://therealtoddnappi.blogspot.com/2012/07/cognos-modeling-guidelines-and-standards.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I removed the circular joins from the model. Basically if I run a test selecting the `Request Amount` from `F_INVOICE_ADJ` and the FACT_LKUP_KEY from `F_CREDIT_ALERT` it works fine. When I click `Auto Sum` it changes the query to a cross join. Cross join SQL: http://pastebin.com/njVtyhFb

Comment: That might be caused by the cardinality between F_INVOICE_ADJ and F_CREDIT_ALERT being 1..N on either side. Cognos may not interpret that properly. An alternative to creating views would be merging the query subjects together to create a virtual star schema. Im not sure if this makes sense for your data but it's a common technique. For instance, first join F_INVOICE_ADJ to D_INVOICE_ADJ, create a new QS, then join that to F_CREDIT_ALERT. Between those two techniques you should be able to control the cardinality properly.